# How can I write an UPDATE in LINQ without fetching the object, changing it, and calling SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm looking for a LINQ query equivalent to:

```
UPDATE Person p SET p.Age = p.Age + 1 WHERE p.Id = 123
```

I know that a solution would be to select the row and then update it like:

```
var p = db.Set<Person>.Where(p => p.Id==123);
p.Age = p.Age + 1;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But this is not a safe way, as before submitting changes someone might increment the value of `Age` and we overwrite that value with a wrong value.

**Question:** Is there a LINQ query that capable of being translated to an update query like this:

```
UPDATE Person p SET p.Age = p.Age + 1 WHERE p.Id = 123
```

Comment: is that always +1 ? or variable

Comment: EF does not *natively* support "in place updates" / "batch updates" / "bulk updates" and requires the two-part method shown first. Use something like https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended and/or another mapper / access layer.

Comment: @brykneval in my case, it is just +1.

Comment: @mehrandvd On the other hand, if just looking to avoid consistency issues (ie. there is no performance consideration updating many many records), consider using a Transaction.

Comment: Don't calculate Age anyway. Record DoB. Calculate age on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot do that with LINQ in default Entity Framework, so options you have are:

1. Just use raw sql query and forget about LINQ  and Entity Framework in this case.
2. Try to use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) library. It has `Update` extension method, so in your case that would be:

   ```
   db.Set<Person>.Where(p => p.Id==123).Update(p => new Person {Age = p.Age + 1});
   ```

   What this library does is parses your expression tree and constructs raw update sql query to your database. For simple cases it should work fine (though of course sql produced by it is not as clean as you can write yourself, but the same is true for EF itself).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Linq method but you you can issue the query via :

```
 var incrementStep = 1;
 var personId = 123;
 db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Person p SET p.Age = p.Age + @p0 WHERE p.Id = @p1",
                                incrementStep, personId);
```

Another way of dealing with your scenario is by handling optimistic concurrency via a row version column that tracks when the row was last changed (for a more complete example and explanation see [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) article).

Comment: It seems that optimistic concurrency is too heavy tool for a simple task of just incrementing a column.

Comment: @Evk it's one way to handle the issue. If it were for me, I'd go with the raw SQL solution instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you need pessimistic logic to handle this case in EF. 
One way that I know is to load the object from the context using SQL statements that contain the locking hint (and do it within a transaction).

However to handle such cases I usually go with stored procedures and bypass the ORM.